# SQL - with Sub Total

Tags: sql

Hi can someone help me be able to add a sub total to my below SQL Query
I would like to know that Subtotal for all the errors i have below.

```
SELECT  EVENT, count(*)
FROM  QMPDATA.PLACEMENT_EVENT 
where EVENT = 'PlacementCreated'
where GRIP_PROCESSED = -1
group BY    EVENT
```

Comment: Why are you using two WHERE clause? Try, SELECT EVENT, COUNT(*) FROM QMPDATA.PLACEMENT_EVENT WHERE EVENT = 'PlacementCreated' AND GRIP_PROCESSED = -1 GROUP BY EVENT

Comment: What's your DBMS? Can you show some data plus expected result? You might want `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((EVENT),())`

Comment: You can use GROUP BY something ROLLUP

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?